# PayPal's Agreement API not sending notification on payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to set up recurring payments for licenses using PHP.

I am using PayPal's Agreement API. Everything "seems" to be working correctly. I am in sandbox mode and I am being redirected to the ReturnURL successfully. However, I am not receiving notifications for the payments made.

The system is going to be set up to receive payment notifications on a monthly basis. Upon receipt of this notification, the license will be extended.

I have set the MerchantPreferences to:

```
$merchant_preferences->setReturnUrl($base_url . '/customers/payments/paypal/?dlms-status=success')
->setCancelUrl($base_url . '/customers/payments/paypal/?dlms-status=cancelled')
->setNotifyUrl($base_url . '/paypal.php')
->setAutoBillAmount('yes')
->setInitialFailAmountAction('CONTINUE')
->setMaxFailAttempts('0');
```

Nothing is being posted by PayPal to https://www.example.com/paypal.php

Can someone please tell me the reason?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view your Sandbox account's IPN history with https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history

Various "Request Bin" type services will let you set up a free listener URL for troubleshooting, for example https://requestbin.com

Comment: I logged in using the sandbox payee account and tried accessing the link above but I get the following error message:

"Instant Payment Notification (IPN) history - Feature Not Available for Personal Account
"

Comment: Use a payee account that is a business account. Create one at https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F

Comment: Are you referring to the sandbox account or production account? If production account then I already have a business account.

Comment: Within the sandbox environment, only sandbox accounts are relevant.  And for this issue only the sandbox payee account you are logging into is in question. It must be a Business account, not a Personal account. Create one as needed.

Comment: If for some reason you were logging into the _payer_ account in sandbox, don't do that. Log into the account that is receiving the payment (the `payee`) to check its IPN history.

Comment: Weird. It didn't work at all yesterday but for some reason, it seems to be working fine today; even though I haven't changed a thing since then.